# Replace string in .txt. any text using othet .txt - VBScript

Tags: string, replace, vbscript

I am new in VBScripting and looking for an advice. 
I have file **1.txt** with some text e.g.

> aaaaaaaaaXXXaaaaaaaaa

I need to change only `XXX` to other text e.g.

> aaaaaaaaaZZZaaaaaaaaa

but `XXX` already exists in second file **2.txt**. I would like to create a file **3.txt** with new string with text

> aaaaaaaaaZZZaaaaaaaaa

Could you help me improve my script?

### What I've got so far is:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(("C:\Script\1.txt"), ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "XXX", "????????????????")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(("C:\Script\3.txt"), ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

Comment: This is a clear http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question

Comment: Your script should work, apart from a newline character added to the output file. Please [edit] your question and specify your aim, i.e. not _how-to_ improve it but  _to-what_ improve it.

Comment: aim:
1.txt  is URL string : eg. wwww.aaaaaaaa.com/aaaaaXXXX/
2.txt is file with new string from created earlier .txt file from popup, so I would like to past variable string in popup and creat new 3.txt
3.txt will be new .txt file with  URL with changed text eg. wwww.aaaaaaaa.com/aaaaaZZZ/
Could you please advise what I need to change in script in place ""????????????????""

Comment: Again: please [edit] your question to improve it. [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) sites are not chat-based. Please take the 2-minute [tour].